# mysql add auto increment and a additional key

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

I am trying to alter a table with adding a new column setting it as auto increment and with a key.

The table already has one key and this one will be an addition. The error I get is the following.

```
error : Multiple primary key defined
```

My code is:

```
alter table user add column id int (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
```

I have also tries wrapping the key name ie

```
alter table user add column id int (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY (id) KEY FIRST;
```

But still no luck.

How can it be done ?

Comment: Show us the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nathan pretty much answered the question.

You find the name(s) of the existing index(es) by using the `SHOW INDEX FROM mydb.mytable` SQL command.

You have to drop the existing index first, using `DROP_INDEX existing_index ON mydb.mytable`.

Then you alter the table and add the primary index with your code.

Finally, you create the other index as a unique index, using `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_index ON mydb.mytable (column)`.

Comment: What is the syntax for 1) finding the index name, 2) dropping the index and 3)creating a unique one?

Comment: See revised answer.  All of this is in the MySQL manual for your particular version of MySQL at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index.html

Answer (score 2):

MySQL doesn't support AUTO_INCREMENT columns that aren't the primary key.  One option is to make the AUTO_INCREMENT column the primary key, and just have a unique constraint on the other 'key'.

Comment: In fact, it does. What it doesn't support is 2 primary keys.

Comment: Wow, you are right @ypercube, I have gone for years thinking otherwise.  The docs are not super clear on that.  Thanks!

Comment: You can add AUTO_INCREMENT on a UNIQUE INDEX too